# how to get value of first column of a tablelayout in android

Tags: android, tablelayout

I am creating an Android application where there is a checkbox and i want to get value of first column of the tablelayout whose checkbox is pressed. I also have a button and i want to get it's value on button press and then i am going to send it back to the server using JSON.

All the fields of the table are dynamically generated and are not stored anywhere. I am fetching the value of the table from the server using JSON and all values are in string format.

I am not able to think about how shall i do it and not able to find any tutorials. Please give me any tutorial link if you have or any piece of code.

[Here is the link](http://pastebin.com/Euj4UT83) to entire code. It is very long but the code of button press is at beginning of the code it self.

I want the value of product code only. you can see it in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: i have added the code. please take a look into it and then do tell me what shall i do to get value of first column from the tablelayout

Comment: Can you add the screen shot of table here? Then it will be easy for everyone to know what values you want.

Comment: i have added the screenshot. i want value of product code. first column whose check box is checked

Comment: You should set the tags for those textviews. You can easily get to know which textviews are under column `products`. `label.setTag(111)` let that be unique and when you want to retrieve that value just use `label.getTag().toString()`. Understood or do you want me to write a code snippet?

Comment: I did add modify the code you told me, but it is causing crash in the application. Can you write a code snippet so that i would know where i am making mistake??

Comment: also when i print the tag value, it is printing 111 only not the content.

Comment: I just used 111. Instead of that you use the value that you put into setText();

Comment: I have added the code, please check it. Don't forget to accept and up vote.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55377/discussion-between-aniruddha-and-samvid-kulkarni).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this -

Create an ArrayList

`ArrayList<String> productList = new ArrayList<String>`

You know which are the textviews under the column `Products`. So when you are setting the textview under that column with some name like `your_tv.setText("sdfsd")`.

Add that string or value into `ArrayList`, like this `productList.add("sdfsd");`. Here add only the values of product column.

By doing this you can easily get the values of Products.

**XML FILE**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

     <TableLayout 
                    android:stretchColumns="0,1"
                    android:id="@+id/main_table" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">
            </TableLayout>


     <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Show"
         android:id="@+id/btn_show"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**JAVA FILE**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TableLayout tl;
    ArrayList<String> productList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] name = { "Product", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
    String[] wt = { "Rs:", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_table);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_show);

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for (int i = 0 ; i < productList.size(); i++)
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), productList.get(i).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

            TableRow tr_head = new TableRow(this);
            tr_head.setId(10);
            tr_head.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            tr_head.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView label_name = new TextView(this);
            label_name.setId(20);
            label_name.setText(name[i]);
            productList.add(name[i]);  // here adding the product name to arraylist
            label_name.setTag(name[i]);
            label_name.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            label_name.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            tr_head.addView(label_name);// add the column to the table row here

            TextView label_weight_kg = new TextView(this);
            label_weight_kg.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
            label_weight_kg.setText(wt[i]);
            label_weight_kg.setTag(wt[i]);// set the text for the header
            label_weight_kg.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); // set the color
            label_weight_kg.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5); // set the padding (if
                                                    // required)
            tr_head.addView(label_weight_kg); // add the column to the table row
                                                // here

            tl.addView(tr_head, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I have added the code so that you can get some idea. Please modify it accordingly. Happy coding :)

Comment: thanks...i am looking into your code and will modify the code accordingly and will do let you know if there any problem